# remove Temp session psdrive

Tags: powershell

I begin to **powershell** and actually I use New-PSDrive with
crendential for create folder and file in my share server. Actually
when my script finish I remove drive but I would like remove
credential information too because windows keep this.

Is it possible?

Actually i use this :

```
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential('test', $pass)
New-PSDrive -Name j -Root \\192.168.1.2220\GOFISecure -Credential $cred -PSProvider FileSystem
```

Comment: By `Windows keeps this` you mean the credential is stored in the Windows Credential Management? If that is the case, you could try and see what you can do using the `cmdkey` utility. I found this blog that may help you: https://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/tip/Clear-cached-credentials-with-the-cmdkey-and-PowerShell

Comment: I believe that you are using the Remove-PSDrive after to remove your connection.
If you write Get-PSDrive is the drive still there listed?
Probably, as I understand, you can access that path after removing the map drive without a credential prompt. Maybe restarting the explorer so the cached credentials are removed?
In general I know that if you log off and on you have to enter again your credentials but I am not sure if a restart on the explorer service will do the trick.

Comment: yes windows keep credential but this no appears in cmdkey /list

Comment: Exactly i remove psdrive in my end script, when i disconnect and reconnect my windows session it's ok i have lose my credential information but when i exec my script psdrive keep this.

Comment: OK windows keep credential informations when wait 15 sec without refresh explorer in file temp but no solution exist for delete file temp directly ?

Comment: Maybe restart the workstation service.
`Get-Service LanmanWorkstation
Stop-service LanmanWorkstation
Start-Service LanmanWorkstation`
Check if this one works for clearing out the "open" session to the share